# Document.write(); Full Include HTML, HEAD, BODY Tag Not Working

Tags: javascript, dom

I am developing a site so that it can be accessed offline.
I've tried and it worked.
But there is a little problem, my content is not structured properly.

Save as `myjs.js`

```
var text = '<html> <head> <title> TEST BRO </title> </head> <body> HELLO WORLD </body> </html>';
document.write (text);
```

On another page, I accessed the script above.
Save as `page.html`

```
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
```

I enable Cache in `.htaccess` to make the content accessible offline.
However, in the inspect element, I see that the `HEAD` tag is empty, and the TITLE tag is inside `BODY`.
How to solve this problem?

I only need JavaScript, not jQuery.
Please help me

Comment: Why `document.write()`?

Comment: @Andreas I want to show the articles that have been stored in the cache, is there any other solution besides document.write?

Comment: Yes, the other solution is to save *the article*, not the full HTML. Afterwords, just place it in the body of the document in a specific container. (e.g, `<div id="atricle">`). Then you can preserve your layout as it is or even change it but the article text would just show up where it should be.

Comment: @VLAZ But it doesn't work for my project, it can't be accessed Offline

Comment: What do you mean? Using `document.write(text)` is exactly the same action as `document.querySelector("#article").textContent = text` in terms of "offline". If you can do one, you can do the other.

Comment: @VLAZ first, visit `page.html`

Comment: Next, visit `data:text/html;base64,BLABLABLA...` its can accesed Offline

Comment: `BLABLABLA` = `<script src="myjs.js"></script>` after convert to `base64`

Comment: @Prabowo this in no way makes it clear. If you can get `mjs.js` in whatever fashion, then it doesn't matter what the content is - `document.write(text)` or `document.querySelector("#article").textContent = text`. And the two operations are the same in that they don't require specific online access. You can't claim to be able to replace the whole documen but then say that you cannot use DOM manipulation, as *they both use the same API*. No difference there. You're just trying to do *more* work by saving the whole document instead of just the part that should change.

Comment: @VLAZ can you put `<title>` into the `Head` tag using `document.querySelector` ?